# By CSS, how to make page height not change when an element is moved down

Tags: html, css

On one page, there are three elements:

```
<body>
    <header />
    <content />
    <footer />
</body>
```

"header"'s CSS definition is:

```
header {
    position: fixed;
    height: 40px;
}
```

In order to present the whole content, I define its CSS like:

```
content {
    margin-top: 40px;
}
```

And bottom's CSS:

```
footer {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Now, the whole page's height is 40px longer than 100% screen height even there is nothing contained in "content". How can I make the whole page height still be 100% of screen? Thanks a lot!

Comment: We need to see the rest of the css (without fancy styling rules) to be able to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `padding-top` on the "content" instead of margin.

Utilising `box-sizing: border-box;` is also recommended.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
.content {
  min-height: 100%;
  padding-top: 40px;
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
}
footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: rgba(0,0,255,0.5);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header></header>
  <div class="content">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur reprehenderit ratione eligendi debitis, atque facilis odit qui sapiente incidunt neque quod possimus illum alias harum dolorem, esse aperiam! Reprehenderit voluptatibus eos autem vel,
      distinctio ullam mollitia dolore est, laborum iste optio eaque illum velit quos illo, harum neque sunt quaerat.
    </p>
  </div>
  <footer></footer>
</body>
```

Note...the footer is still on top of the "content" div and will obscure any content there. Other options exist for more flexible footers.

Comment: A `padding-bottom: 50px;` and `overflow: auto` would fix _obscured content_, right :)

Comment: If you fix the misstyped `.content {
  height: min-100%;` it will work nice :) ... http://jsfiddle.net/j2vzrmer/2/

Comment: My point is that the footer still won't move and if it not-transparent it will still obscure the content. - http://jsfiddle.net/j2vzrmer/4/

Comment: I understand your point, though still this fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/j2vzrmer/2/, solves it ... I just added `padding-bottom: 50px;` and `overflow: auto` to your original snippet (and not `min-height` on the content, just `height: 100%`).